# Number of rational points of a singular cubic surface over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-surfaces, rational-points

I have a (geometrically irreducible) cubic surface defined over a finite field $F_q$ with three non-$F_q$-rational singularities (defined over the cubic extension of $F_q$).

Counting the number of $F_{q^3}$-rational points is easy by projection from a singular point.

What can be said about the number of $F_q$-rational points of the surface?

I would like upper/lower bounds that are finer than the Lang-Weil bound.

Thanks,
  H.

Comment: The number $N_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points of your cubic surface is congruent to $1$ modulo $q$ by the Chevalley-Warning theorem.

Comment: There is at least one $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational point by Chevalley-Warning.  If this point is contained in no line contained in the hypersurface, the tangent planar cubic at this point contains $q$ points, resp. $q+1$ points depending on whether it is nodal, resp. cuspidal.  You can iterate the construction of the tangent planar cubic with each of those points.

Comment: Resolving singularities gives a map $\pi \colon Y \to X$ where $Y$ is a generalised del Pezzo surface.  Since your singularities aren't defined over the base field, I guess $\pi$ will give a bijection on $\mathbb{F}_q$-points.  You can count points on $Y$ using the Weil conjectures, which in this case comes down to $q^2+1+q$(trace of Frobenius on $\mathrm{Pic}\ Y$).  You have $\mathrm{Pic}\ Y \cong \mathbb{Z}^7$ and the Galois action depends on whether your singularities are $A_1$ or $A_2$ and the Galois action on the lines on $X$.